# extract controls using Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, reflection

If I have a application form say `Form1` which has `DataGridView`. Therefore the assembly name would be `Test.exe`. By using Reflection, if I have inputs for physical location of assembly and Form name `Form1`, can I extract `datagridview`?

Comment: So you want extract `DataGrid` from another application?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean my 'extract datagridview'?

Comment: Tigran: Yes.I need to extract DataGrid from other application

Comment: Chris: I Need to get datagrid,control from other application.

Comment: You cannot access controls in another process, only code that runs inside that process can do this.  The code injection is highly nontrivial, look at "Managed Spy" for ideas.  First google hit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the assembly into the AppDomain using `Assembly.LoadFrom` and then create an instance of Form1, by using `Activator.CreateInstance` and the full qualified name of Form1. Then you can get the type information of Form1 by calling `GetType()` on the instance of the form, enumerate all fields and take the one that is of type DataGridView. Using the instance of Form1 and the type information you can get the instance of DataGridView.